# Does React Native Wrap Native APIs?

Tags: react-native

Does React Native wrap all the native API calls in Javascript? For example, if I wanted to customize a UI element, can I call native methods on that element using Javascript?

Is it possible to call native camera APIs without a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not do that. React Native only created a few core APIs that wrap, or rather bridge, to native APIs. If you want to access other APIs not covered in the core React Native library, you have to create the wrapper to do these custom native API calls from JavaScript. [These docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) show how to create native modules and [these docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) show you how to create a custom native UI component.

**EDIT**:

The closest you can get to calling native methods on a UI element is by calling `setNativeProps` on a UI element that implements it, but it is only limited to setting props natively, not specific UI element methods.

And to answer the camera question more directly, you can't. You must depend on a plugin that you install from the community, like `react-native-camera` or you make a native module for it.

Comment: Why the down vote? Any reason? If you think I was promoting NativeScript, I am not. I don't use it anymore. And if you think it was unnecessary to mention, I edited my answer and removed the mention.